# Remove last character "dash" from url

Tags: mod-rewrite, iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I am trying to remove last "dash" from my website url's using IIS Rewrite Mod.

Example:

/serie/fiche/50444/the-fosters-2013- 
redirect 301 to 
/serie/fiche/50444/the-fosters-2013 (without the last dash)

I've already try some rules but none works:

```
<rule name="dash problem" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^addictlive.com([A-Za-z0-9-_/]*)([-])$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://addictlive.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

and

```
<rule name="dash problem" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^addictlive.com/([A-Za-z0-9-_/]*)([-])" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://addictlive.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Nothing works.

Please anyone know how to do ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution:

```
<rule name="dash problem" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)-$" />
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
```